# How often can you write to a socket when uploading through FTP?

Tags: sockets, ftp

I'm working on an integrated FTP upload module and using code online I've found this method is called at intervals of 300 milliseconds:

```
var uploadInterval:int = 300;
var bufferSize:uint = 4096;

private function sendData():void {
    var sourceBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    sourceFile.readBytes(sourceBytes, 0, bufferSize);

    passiveSocket.writeBytes(sourceBytes, 0, sourceBytes.bytesAvailable);
    passiveSocket.flush();

    if (sourceFile.bytesAvailable < bufferSize) {
        bufferSize = sourceFile.bytesAvailable;
    }
}

interval = setInterval(sendData, uploadInterval);
```

If I set the interval to 5 ms the file uploads in 10 seconds. If I set it 300 ms it loads in around 37 seconds. Is it alright to set it to 5ms instead of 300?

**Update:**
It looks like there is a commented out command that is using blocking mode. I searched more online and it looks like it's using an interval to be able to get upload progress information. Anyway, here is the original commented out method. I haven't tested it:

```
private function sendBlockData():void {

    var bytes:int;
    var sourceBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    sourceFile.readBytes(sourceBytes, bytes, Math.min(bufferSize, sourceFile.bytesAvailable - bytes));
    bytes += bufferSize;
    bufferSize = Math.min(bufferSize, sourceFile.bytesAvailable - bytes);

    passiveSocket.writeBytes(sourceBytes, 0, sourceBytes.bytesAvailable);
    passiveSocket.flush();

}
```

Comment: You can write as fast as you like in blocking mode. It will block when the pipe is full. No need for an interval at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the socket is blocking, as is usually the default you can write as fast as you can and the write() call will block until the OS can take more data.

So I don't know why the code you found is waiting some milliseconds between write() calls, in the general case you loop and send all your available data without waiting. The OS takes care of blocking the sender when needed.

Comment: OK. I found someone online saying it's so they could get progress events. If you upload in chunks you can track the position of the byte array.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts You'll get those anyway, spaced out by however long it takes to actually write the data you send. The larger the buffer, the less frequent the events. The extra waits are just literally a waste of time.

Comment: Progress events from the sockets? Hmmm so if I wanted to get events frequently could I increase the buffer size? It's at 4096? Yes, it's literally a waste of time!

Comment: I went on to asdocs and found that a new progress event is dispatched that is possibly exactly for this purpose. So I can send all the data in one go and still get events. http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/08/socket-improvements-in-air-3.html